# How to obtain a lock in DB2 with select for update without transferring data?

Tags: java, jdbc, db2, locking

Through a ton of experiments I found that

*([`jdbcTemplate` is a `JdbcTemplate`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html) and is just used to make execution of queries easy. It has no real relation to the question)*

```
jdbcTemplate.query(
    "select 0 from example where id = 23 for update with rs use and keep update locks", 
    rs -> {
        rs.next();
        return null;
});
```

obtains a lock on the selected row, while this one doesn't:

```
jdbcTemplate.query(
    "select 0 from example where id = 23 for update with rs use and keep update locks", 
    rs -> {
        return null;
});
```

I assume for the same reason the following does not obtain a lock:

```
jdbcTemplate.execute(
    "select id from example where id = 23 for update with rs use and keep update locks"
);
```

I have a two part question:

1. What the heck is going on?
2. How can I execute the select for update in the database so it does result in the lock, but does not return data per selected row? Maybe some kind of script?

[There is a Github repository testing these (and many more variants)](https://github.com/schauder/db2-locks).

Comment: In your test, is autocommit enabled?

Comment: No, they run with Springs explicit transaction control via a TransactionTemplate.

Comment: Try `select count(1) from example where id = 23 with rs use and keep update locks`. All the rows affected (if there are multiple ones) should be locked during `open`.

Comment: @MarkBarinstein this does indeed work, even when executed with `execute`. Do you want to make an answer? Do you have an explanation what is going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Citation from the documentation on [Read Stability (RS)](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.perf.doc/doc/c0004121.html?view=kc#c0004121__rs) isolation level:

> The read stability isolation level locks only those rows that an
>   application **retrieves** during a unit of work.

```
-- Rows are locked / accessed during "fetch"
select * from example where id = 23 with rs use and keep update locks;

-- Rows must be accessed either during "execute" / "open" or "fetch" to get the corresponding result
select count(1) from example where id = 23 with rs use and keep update locks;
```

The main requirement to achieve `RS` is in other words: if some row participated in the result of the 1-st call of this statement, then it must participate in the results of each subsequent call of the same statement with the same values.

When you just select rows, they are retrieved (accessed) during `fetch` only. They are not accessed until you fetch them. There is no need to lock these rows beforehand to achieve the logical goal described above. Why to decrease the system concurrency, if you may "lazy" fetch / lock the rows needed?

But when you make some aggregation on the rows needed, they must be accessed either during `execute` / `open` or during the 1-st `fetch` (and the only `fetch`, since it's aggregation) to lock the corresponding rows. I believe, that such a behavior is not documented - it's only current observed behavior.

I'd suggest you to do 1 `fetch` on the aggregation statement anyway to be on the safe side. Nobody can guarantee (except if you ask IBM Support on this and get the corresponding clarification), that such a behavior may not change in future.